# How to properly write a destructor for this

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

I have a simple struct, friends would be allocated with `new`, so obviously I need to `delete` that. However, with name and email I am not so sure.

```
struct Member
{
    char * name;
    char * email;
    LinkedList<Member> * friends;

    Member() : name(nullptr), email(nullptr), friends(nullptr)
    {
    }

    ~Member()
    {
        if (friends)
            delete friends;
    }
};
```

What if, for example, I have

```
Member m;
m.name = "John Doe";
m.email = "johnDoe0@email.com";
```

Do I still need to `delete` name/email?

Comment: Why a `struct` here? Having public pointers like that is asking for trouble.

Comment: If you always initialize these members that way, you should have `const char * name;` and don't call `delete` for them.

Comment: Why use pointers at all? Including the strings (you do know about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), yes?)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes I do, but it would be too easy. I am just trying to learn. I am not going to use this code anywhere else.

Comment: @MichaelNaumov Why is `friends` a pointer?  (For that matter, regardless of what you're doing, you shouldn't be using `char*` for string values.  If you don't want to use `std::string`, the first thing you should do is write a simple string class yourself, which does deep copy.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `std::string` instead of `char*`. That will solve your problem. Otherwise this will be cumbersome ... you will need a flag to let the destructor know how the name was allocated (via `new` via `*alloc` or just a plain constant) and act accordingly (ie: if it was `alloc`'ed the `free` it if it was `new`'d then `delete` it, if it was initialized via a constant... you don't have to do anything).

Comment: thanks, I am just doing this for self learning. It does not have any practical purpose besides it, so I am trying to avoid STL to get better understanding of how things work underneath.

Comment: @MichaelNaumov Ok, in this case simply track the origin of the string (ie: how did you allocate it). Although for tiny pieces of code (like this) which use only basic types of variable in practice it does not matter if you `delete` something which was `malloc`'d (there will be no memory leaks, however valgrind will report a Mismatched free() / delete / delete []) it is not a good habit to start using these in the unproper way because later when you start doing object allocations, it actually matters. So use the C++ allocations together and the C allocations together.

Answer (score 7):

The rule of thumb is: Only `delete` what you `new` (and `delete[]` what you `new[]`).

In this case you do not allocate memory for the character pointers, you make them point to constant arrays of characters instead, so you should of course not `delete` them.

Also note that it's valid to do `delete` on a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a class instead of a structure, with attributes like name email .. etc, and then you'll just have to delete the entire member ?

Comment: `class` and `struct` are basically to ways of saying the same thing in C++. You can define exactly the same types using either.

Comment: struct is the same as class in C++ except that it's public by default. And I am just being lazy here with using proper encapsulation :)